# Regex to check input is not empty plus it's alphanumeric?

Tags: regex

I need a single regex to check if input must not be empty plus the input has alphanumeric characters only.

I know the alphanumeric part,`^[\s+0-9a-zA-Z]+$`, but I am not sure about the not empty requirement.

I can only use a single expression and I can't use any language function.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this regex to match a non-empty alphanumeric string:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

*Details*

- `^` - string start
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `$` - string end.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks for improving it!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume by Not empty you mean not only white space, otherwise you've got the answer you want. `+` means one or more.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*^
```

will make sure that the string has something other than white space in it.

<strike>Additionally if `\s` is valid then I assume `\w` is as well, meaning that this could more easily be said as</strike>

```
^[(?:\w|\s)*$
```

The `?:` in the `( )` makes it a non-capture group. If you don't care about capture then this can be omitted, making it the very terse.

```
^\w(\w|\s)*$
```

Comment: I think that alpha-numeric does not include underscore `_`. Also, I think that `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is the `[:alnum:]` class, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the `[:word:]` class. `[:alnum:]` is a standard class, `[:word:]` is an extension. So you are correct.